# С чего начать писать графический редактор?

Tags: графика, c++, блок-схема

Стоит задача написать графический редактор блок-схем. Не особо навороченный, но и не самый примитивный. Я это понимаю так: берутся различного рода вида фигуры (могут перемещаться, удаляться, иметь свои свойства и т.д.) и кладутся на холст. В принципе всё. Интересует следующее:

1. Что выбрать в качестве среды разработки?
2. Как работать с графикой (кубы, ромбы, треугольники внутри с текстом), именно что использовать для отрисовки фигур?

Заранее благодарю за дельные ответы.

Comment: А зачем, собственно говоря, это делать? Их уже столько, что сводит скулы. 

Comment: задание на курсовой проект.

Comment: свою онлайн-рисовалку на js я начал с разработки интерфейса. Думаю правильно сделал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую Вам использовать библиотеку Qt. В ней присутствуют все необходимые для данной задачи классы.

Comment: Смотрел в сторону Qt, много преимуществ. Но есть одно НО, скорее всего будет ограничение в сторону VisualStudio, если с ней работать что посоветуете использовать?

Comment: Если будет привязка к Visual Studio, просто как к среде разработки, я посоветую использовать плагин Qt Visual Studio Add-In. Субъективно, работать в Visual Studio не так приятно, как в Qt Creator. Но использование QGraphicsScene с лихвой окупит все неудобства.

Comment: QGraphicScene отлично подойдет для редактора блок-схем. Там уже реализовано перемещение, масштабирование и прочие прелести графических редакторов.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Среду нужно выбирать ту, в которой есть опыт работы. И ещё нужно определиться с операционной системой. Кто знает, может под Мак хотите... Но к примеру Qt покроет большинство платформ. Но он немного сложен, что бы так, с наскока за денек осилить.
2. Работать просто - просто берем и рисуем. Рекомендую делать массив (дерево) объектов, которые могут сами рисоваться на канве.

Comment: по поводы канвы не будет ли торможения и перерисовки всего контента? хотелось бы сделать холст и объекты независимыми

Comment: Если редактор не сложный - не будет

Comment: Если рисовать правильно, то проблем не будет. Если не правильно - то будут:)
Правильно - это в обработчике onDraw/WM_PAINT или подобных.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказки.

Answer (score 1):

Было бы круто если бы он работал через фрагментный шейдер OpenGL. Заодно разберетесь немного в базовых принципах 3D графики. Хотя наверное это слишком сложно для редактора блок-схем.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю что это такое и с чем его едят, но наверное будет слишком сложно))

Answer (score 1):

В качестве средства для непосредственно рисования фигур можно ещё рассмотреть такую библиотеку, как [graphviz.](http://graphviz.org/)

В ней основная идея в том, что она умеет сама располагать и отрисовывать элементы, но если нужно реализовать перетаскивание, то можно и задавать координаты любому элементу "вручную".

Вроде как даже [туториал](http://www.mupuf.org/blog/2010/07/08/how_to_use_graphviz_to_draw_graphs_in_a_qt_graphics_scene/) есть.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой свободный редактор [dia](https://live.gnome.org/Dia/Development). Он, правда, на С написан, на первый взгляд. Можете его глянуть и подумать над архитектурой. Только с git'а у меня исходники скачать не получилось: apt-get source помог.

---

По поводу среды разработки, лично мне с графикой больше всего понравилось работать в Qt - сначала идет туговато, а когда понимаешь принцип - влет.
А технология проста и стандартна - общий абстрактный предок и куча разных потомков.

Comment: технология понятна, не мог определиться в чем делать графику. посмотрю в сторону Qt, ну или поизвращаюсь с OpenGL.

Comment: OpenGL более функционален от этого и отталкивайся

Answer (score 0):

Стволовым функционалом любого редактора является пара функций Undo/Redo. Они как бы образуют собой ось времени, относительно которой происходит всё остальное - создаются, удаляются и трансформируются объекты, изменяются их свойства, происходит выделение и "развыделение" объектов, осуществляется перевод фокуса между объектами, изменяется масштаб отображения. В идеальном редакторе все эти вещи должны быть отменяемы. Причём каждая на оптимальную для данной операции глубину. Понятно, что для перевода фокуса и выделения достаточно небольшой глубины, чтобы можно было отменить сделанное только что. А вот для операций с объектами нужна большая глубина. В идеале - бесконечная. Причём весьма специфически организованная. Простейших операций для пошагового перемещения по оси времени недостаточно. Должна быть возможность вернуться к варианту, который "вроде был ещё не такой убогий, и это было где-то час назад", вдумчиво посмотреть на него, и, поняв, что здесь он ещё не совсем закончен, скакнуть минут на десять вперед.

Проектирование нужно начинать именно с этого. Функции Undo/Redo нужно сделать так, чтобы весь остальной функционал, который будет в редакторе, было легко с ними совместить.

Comment: Ответ мне понравился, но один раз я его уже плюсанул (в вопросе от @Вячеслав1101)

Comment: Очень познавательно. Большое спасибо, есть над чем задуматься. Конструктивный ответ. Буду отталкиваться от этого.